# Model in dynamic repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a weird problem with dynamic binding of model in Angular JS.

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in [].constructor( 5 ) track by $index">
  <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
    <input type="text" ng-model="column.defaults[i]" class="form-control">
  </td>
</tr>
```

I define columns using:

```
  $scope.addColumn = function() {
    if(!$scope.field_column_name) return;

    if(!$scope.columns) {
      $scope.columns = []
    }
    $scope.columns.push( {
      name: $scope.field_column_name,
      defaults: $scope.field_column_defaults
    });
    $scope.field_column_name = $scope.field_column_default = undefined;
  };
```

My goal is create inputs for all of it to store data added by user. The problem is, because all inputs looks like if they were the same model (value added in one of them shows also in other inputs). Why?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tz6fsz1o/5/

Comment: Show how you define columns in your controller

Comment: @suvroc I added method

Comment: i tried to reproduce your error but without success: http://jsfiddle.net/tz6fsz1o/1/ try to do this in JsFiddle

Comment: @Siper i have been able to reproduce, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31z5grt3/2/) i believe your suffering a pass by reference issue (i do not fully understand the inner workings of JS so could be using wrong terminology there.). Your defaults all originate from the same variable `$scope.field_column_defaults`. If you comment that out and give them an empty array it works. [Demo with comment](https://jsfiddle.net/31z5grt3/1/). EDIT i posted the wrong fiddle. The first link now does reproduce the error.

Comment: Ach, I know why, in production I'm using `[].constructor(5)` instead of `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tz6fsz1o/3/

Comment: @Siper but that doesn't do what you want either? The defaults are not filled in and each column updates when you update just one? EDIT: besides `[].constructor(5)` doesn't seem to do what your expect. Chrome it gives an empty array, IE its gives an array with 5 elements that are empty. Generally speaking i would avoid doings things like that in your view anyway.

Comment: Check that, this is my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/tz6fsz1o/5/

Comment: Please update your answer clarifying your issue as im now confused. You say there all updating with the same value in each column and thats wrong? Yet the example you give in your comments have that behavior? In my first comment, the second link is that the behavior you want each column to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistake in creating `rows_array`

Try http://jsfiddle.net/tz6fsz1o/6/

```
$scope.$watch('rows', function(){
    $scope.rows_array = [];
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.rows;i++){
        $scope.rows_array.push(i);
    }
  }, true);
```

Comment: This is it what have I done and works perfect :) I just used this instead of loop: `Array.apply(null, {length: $scope.rows}).map(Number.call, Number);`

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea. I use loop to show what you should do in simple way

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in [].constructor(5)" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
        <input type="text" ng-model="columns[$index].defaults[outerIndex]" class="form-control">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Note how you need to store outer loop `$index` into helper variable in order to access it in inner loop.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tz6fsz1o/7/

Answer (score 0):

You are *binding* each field on `ng-model="column.defaults[i]"`, it means that each field present in the `columns` array will be binded on the same model property... ex: both `column.foo` and `column.bar` bind to `columnt.default[i]`...

You can fix it binding the text field on the `column` variable, for example:

```html
<td ng-repeat="column in columns">
        <input type="text" ng-model="column.foo" class="form-control">
</td>
```